# Taking free abelian groups "commutes" with quotient by equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Is the following result true? (I hope so because I've given a proof...)

Many thanks!

---

**Claim.** Let $S$ be a (non-empty) set and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $S.$

The natural map $S\to S/\sim$ induces an isomorphism
$$F(S)/\langle\{s-s' \, : \, s,s' \in S \;\text{ with }\; s\sim s'\}\rangle \to F(S/\sim)$$
where $F$ is the "free abelian group" functor.

---

*Proof.* The quotient map $S\to S/\sim$ induces a surjective group hom $$\Phi:F(S) \to F(S/\sim)$$
$$\sum_{s \in S}a_s s \longmapsto \sum_{s \in S}a_s[s]$$
where the $a_s$ are integers almost all of which are zero.

It is clear that any element of $F(S)$ of the form $s-s'$ where $s\sim s'$ is in $\ker \Phi$.

Conversely, if $\sum_{s \in S} a_s s$ is in the kernel, then, for each $[s] \in S/\sim,$ one has
$$\sum_{t \in [s]}a_t=0.$$
Fix some $[s] \in S/\sim.$ If there exists $t \in [s]$ such that $a_t\neq0,$ then we have
$$a_t=-\sum_{u \in [s] \\ \,u\neq t}a_u$$
and so we can write
$$\sum_{v \in [s]} a_v v = \sum_{u \in [s] \\ \,u\neq t}a_u(u-t)$$
and so the result follows.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is true, and your proof works (up to the missing sign in $a_t = -\sum_{u \in [s], u \neq t} a_u$).

Another way to prove this statement is to construct a pair of inverse homomorphisms
$$
  \varphi \colon F(S)/N \to F(S/{\sim})
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  \psi \colon F(S/{\sim}) \to F(S)/N
$$
(where $N = \langle s - s' \mid s, s' \in S, s \sim s' \rangle$) by using the universal properties of the various objects involved:

You have already mentioned that the canonical projection $S \to S/{\sim}$, $s \mapsto [s]$  induces a group homomorphism
$$
          \Phi
  \colon  F(S)
  \to     F(S/{\sim}),
  \quad   \sum_{s \in S} a_s s
  \mapsto \sum_{s \in S} a_s [s],
$$
and that $N \subseteq \ker \Phi$.
It follows that $\Phi$ induces a well-defined homomorphism
$$
          \varphi
  \colon  F(S)/N
  \to     F(S/{\sim}),
  \quad   \left[ \sum_{s \in S} a_s s \right]
  \mapsto \sum_{s \in S} a_s [s].
$$

To construct $\psi$ we start with the canonical inclusion $S \to F(S)$, $s \mapsto s$.
Then the composition
$$
          S
  \to     F(S)
  \to     F(S)/N,
  \quad   s
  \mapsto [s]
$$
maps $s, s' \in S$ with $s \sim s'$ onto the same element, and thus induces a well-defined map
$$
          S/{\sim}
  \to     F(S)/N,
  \quad   [s]
  \mapsto [s].
$$
By the universal property of the free group, this map induces a well-defined homomorphism
$$
          \psi
  \colon  F(S/{\sim})
  \to     F(S)/N,
  \quad   \sum_{[s] \in S/{\sim}} b_{[s]} [s]
  \mapsto \sum_{[s] \in S/{\sim}} b_{[s]} [s]
  =       \left[ \sum_{[s] \in S/{\sim}} b_{[s]} s \right].
$$

Checking that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other can be done on generators:
The group $F(S)$ is generated by the elements $s \in S$, so $F(S)/N$ is generated by the elements $[s]$ with $s \in S$;
the group $F(S/{\sim})$ is generated by th elements $[s]$ with $[s] \in S/{\sim}$, i.e. by the elements $[s]$ with $s \in S$.
For every $s \in S$ we have that
$$
    \varphi(\psi([s]))
  = \varphi([s])
  = [s],
$$
and similarly
$$
    \psi(\varphi([s]))
  = \psi([s])
  = [s].
$$
So we have that $\varphi \circ \psi = \operatorname{id}$ and $\psi \circ \varphi = \operatorname{id}$, showing that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism with $\varphi^{-1} = \psi$.

Comment: Many thanks! I corrected the missing minus sign in my original post.